# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы бот авторизировался на каком-либо сайте discord py

Tags: python, requests, discord.py, request

Не знаю возможно ли такое реализовать или нет, но в общем.

Нужно чтобы бот авторизовался на сайте и вывел оттуда весь html код.

Позже уже после обработки кода выводил нужную информацию

Заранее спасибо

Форма авторизации
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICo3X.png

Answer (score 0):

Возможно. Но сайты на хостинге висят, а там всякого рода защита есть.

Трудно будет это все реализовать)